# How to access a $_POST item through the following array kind of syntax?

Tags: php, arrays, post, cgi

If i send four POST variables, but the second one — I dont know that the `name=""` tag will be; how can I access it?  Can i use `$_POST[1]` or not?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution using internal pointers:

```
if(count($_POST) > 1){ // just a check here.
  reset($_POST); // reset the pointer regardless of its position
  $second_value = next($_POST); // get the next value, aka 2nd element.
}
```

By the way with regards to the numeric index: PHP $_POST and $_GET are associative arrays! They do not support something like `$_POST[0]` or `$_POST[1]`. They will return NULL because they are not set. Instead `$_POST["name"]` would work.

From the PHP Manual: "An **associative array** of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST (or GET) method."

Comment: The simple approach is often the easiest -- converting the array using array_values() and then indexing into it works like a charm.

Comment: @csl - overhead of an additional variable =D joking!

Answer (score 2):

i have a handy function for this

```
function nth($ary, $n) {
     $b = array_slice($ary, intval($n), 1); 
     return count($b) ? reset($b) : null;
}
```

in your case

```
$foo = nth($_POST, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){
    if( is_int($key) ) //do something with $value
}
```

This will work if you know the other $_POST values have names in your forms (i.e., keys that aren't numbers).

Comment: Mauris is right and my answer is wrong. If you post a value that doesn't have a name it will return NULL and will not be set in the $_POST associative array.

Comment: even if it has a name, the numeric index will still not be set. =)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through it:

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
  if (substr($k, 0, 3) == 'id_') { 
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

But it really depends on what the criteria for the search is. In the above example it's pulling all the POST variables that start with "id_". You may be able to do it simpler if you have a different/better criteria.

Comment: but he only wants to access one variable. the loop seems excessive

Answer (score 0):

You can if you convert it using [array_values()](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) first.

**Example**

```
<?php

$a = array(
        "first key" => "first value",
        "second key" => "second value",
);

$v = array_values($a);
echo "First value: {$v[0]}\n";

?>
```

**Output**

```
$ php -f a.php
First value: first value
```

*EDIT:* Thanks for commentators pointing out the initial error.

Comment: According to PHP Manual on $_POST: "An **associative** array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method."

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

this will give you an idea of what is the key of the field you don't know.

Comment: That's useless. Obviously it's unknown at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy :

```
$vars = $_POST;
```

Remove the names you know :

```
unset( $vars[ "known variable 1" ] );
unset( $vars[ "known variable 2" ] );
```

All that remains is the variables you need : extract them with array_values or enumerate them with foreach, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

a simple for each will do the trick if you do not know the array keys on the $_POST array

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value):
   print 'key'.$key.' value'.$value
endforeach;
```

But it is recommended to know what your post variables are if you are planning on processing them.